# Display under sub-comment according to parent sub-comment

Tags: html, mysql, twig

I have a problem to display sub-comments based on a parent sub-comment. I do not know if it's a twig or query problem or other.

I have a reply table that contains sub-comments that are linked to the comments in my comments table with the field (com_id).

Only the com_id field of my reply table also refers to the reply_id field of the same table if the reply_level is equal to 1 (see image, red line diagonal).

[image: table comment]

[image: table reply]

How do I make a query to select the reply_level (1), reply_id(6) based on the reply_id parent (reply_id (4)?

My twig code:

```html
<h3 class="titleComments">Comments</h3>
    {% for comment in comments %}
        <p> <strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong> {{ comment.content }}</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn-primary btn-xs buttonAnswer btnLevel0" value="{{ comment.id }}"  > answer </button>
    <div id="reply">
        {% if replys is defined %}
            {% for reply in replys %}
                {% if reply.getComParent() == comment.id and reply.level == 0%}
                    <p> <strong>{{ reply.author }}</strong> {{ reply.content }}</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-primary btn-xs buttonAnswer btnLevel1" value="{{ reply.id }}" data-level="{{ reply.level1 }}" > answer </button>
                {% endif %}
                <div id="underReply1">
                    {% if reply.getComParent() ==  reply.id  and reply.level ==1 %}
                        <p> <strong>{{ reply.author }}</strong> {{ reply.content }}</p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-primary btn-xs buttonAnswer btnLevel2" value="{{ reply.id }}" data-level="{{ reply.level2 }}" > answer </button>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% else %}
       no comment(s).
    {% endfor %}
```

result :

[image: result]

The child sub How does not appear. It appears that if I add a fourth main comment. It works from sub comment to comment but I can not call a sub-comment based on the parent sub-comment.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure `reply_level` is an integer?

Comment: Yes it's an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursivity is the magic word to do an arbitrary number of loops according to the deepness of something.

In your case, you can try something like this:

```
<h3 class="titleComments">Comments</h3>

{# imports macros contained in this file inside "me" variable #}
{% import _self as me %}

{# makes the variable exists and loopable whatever the case #}
{% set replies = replies|default([]) %}

{% for comment in comments %}
    <p><strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong> {{ comment.content }}</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn-primary btn-xs buttonAnswer btnLevel0" value="{{ comment.id }}"> answer</button>

    {# fixes the non-unique id issue in your current code #}
    <div id="reply-{{ comment.id }}">
         {% if replies|length %}
             {% for reply in replies %}
                 {% if reply.getComParent() == comment.id and reply.level == 0 %}
                     <p> <strong>{{ reply.author }}</strong> {{ reply.content }}</p>
                     <button type="button" class="btn-primary btn-xs buttonAnswer btnLevel{{ level }}" value="{{ reply.id }}" data-level="{{ reply.level1 }}" > answer </button>

                     {# here begins the magic #}
                     {{ me.displayReplies(replies, reply, 1) }}

                 {% endif %}
             {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            no comment(s).
        {% endif %}
     </div>
{% endfor %}

{# macros are similar to functions in php and can call themselves recursivly #}
{% macro displayReplies(replyParent, replies, level) %}

    {# reimports macros to make this macro able to call himself #}
    {% import _self as me %}

    {% for replyChild in replies %}

    <div id="underReply{{ replyParent.id }}">
        {% if replyChild.getComParent() == replyParent.id and replyChild.level == level %}
            <p> <strong>{{ replyChild.author }}</strong> {{ replyChild.content }}</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn-primary btn-xs buttonAnswer btnLevel2" value="{{ replyChild.id }}" data-level="{{ replyChild.level2 }}" > answer </button>

            {# and we get deeper if needed #}
            {{ me.displayReplies(replyChild, replies, level + 1) }}

        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% endmacro %}
```

---

By the way, a simpler approach should be to use the same table for comments and replies:

Considering the following context:

```
comments:
    -
        id: 1
        parent_id: null
        content: comment 1
    -
        id: 2
        parent_id: null
        content: comment 2
    -
        id: 3
        parent_id: null
        content: comment 3
    -
        id: 4
        parent_id: 1
        content: reply comment 1
    -
        id: 5
        parent_id: 2
        content: reply comment 2
    -
        id: 6
        parent_id: 3
        content: reply comment 3
    -
        id: 7
        parent_id: 3
        content: reply comment 3
    -
        id: 8
        parent_id: 4
        content: reply of reply comment 3
    -
        id: 9
        parent_id: 8
        content: reply of reply of reply comment 3
```

And the following twig code:

```
{% import _self as me %}

{% macro displayComment(comments, parentComment, deepness = 0) %}

  {% if parentComment.parent_id is null %}
  Comment #{{ parentComment.id }} (deepness = {{ deepness }}): {{ parentComment.content }}
  {% else %}
    {% for i in 0..deepness %}  {% endfor %}Reply #{{ parentComment.id }} of #{{ parentComment.parent_id }} (deepness = {{ deepness }}): {{ parentComment.content }}
  {% endif %}

  {% import _self as me %}
  {% for childComment in comments if childComment.parent_id == parentComment.id %}
  {{ me.displayComment(comments, childComment, deepness + 1) }}
  {% endfor %}

{% endmacro %}

{% for comment in comments if comment.parent_id is null %}
{{ me.displayComment(comments, comment) }}
{% endfor %}
```

You will end up with:

```
Comment #1 (deepness = 0): comment 1

    Reply #4 of #1 (deepness = 1): reply comment 1

        Reply #8 of #4 (deepness = 2): reply of reply comment 3

            Reply #9 of #8 (deepness = 3): reply of reply of reply comment 3

Comment #2 (deepness = 0): comment 2

    Reply #5 of #2 (deepness = 1): reply comment 2

Comment #3 (deepness = 0): comment 3

    Reply #6 of #3 (deepness = 1): reply comment 3

    Reply #7 of #3 (deepness = 1): reply comment 3
```

[See fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/uixru8)

Comment: Thanks for the code, it's complicated, Do I have to copy the code exactly as it is? Because it does not work, I have this error : Twig_Error_Runtime in article.html.twig line 28 :
Key "length" does not exist as the array is empty ((    {% if replies.length %} )).
I will continue to seek with this solution

Comment: Sorry, this is `replies|length`.

Comment: I have no more errors but now I have only the main comments that appear : [link](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=348279error.png)

Comment: You should var_export both `replies` and `comments` so I'll be able to debug. Can you add those information in your question? Thanks

Comment: you should var_export those variables with php, not with twig - the goal is to reproduce your case so have the right context

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this logic:

```
<div id="underReply1">
   {% if reply.getComParent() == comment.id and reply.level == 1 %}
   ...
```

I think that's what you need. Since the reply id might not match the com parent. I'm not certain it will fix the problem, but please try it and see if those are the results you are expecting.

Comment: No I already try, that's the problem. If I do this, the sub-comment will link to the parent comment (main commentary) and not to the parent sub-comment.